# Converting impersonal constructions to modal sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

In these examples:

> **It is** required that we file taxes.
>   **It is** crucial for my friend to be here.
>   **It is** possible that humans are on the edge of breathtaking discoveries..

How can I convert these impersonal constructions so that it doesn't start with a dummy pronoun?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part (the last sentence is a bit different), you can reverse and slightly rephrase your sentences:

> Filing taxes is required of us.
>   My friend's presence here is crucial.
>   Humans might be on the edge of breathtaking discoveries.